# can't find java.awt.Desktop

Tags: java, swing, desktop

I'm looking for the class java.awt.Desktop

I think it has something to do with Swing, but I'm not sure what that is. From the little bit I read, It only exists on Java 1.6, which I'm using. Still, under java.awt, all I have is "font".

Is anyone familiar with this? Can tell me if I have to download anything in order for this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Comment: [docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "looking"? Trying to autocomplete in an IDE?

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something in these links, but they don't explain why I don't have java.awt.desktop in my code, or how to import it

Comment: lowercase `desktop` won't work. It's `Desktop`.

Comment: Thilo, I know. The line "import java.awt.Desktop" gives an error;

Comment: Please show the exact line of code (and maybe the ones around it) and the error message.

Comment: I try importing the class
import java.awt.Desktop;
but there is a red 'x' on the left, when I hover over, it says "the import java.awt.Desktop" cannot be resolved

Comment: I mean, how do you find out about it so that you now think you need it? Maybe you check from the same source how to get it.

Comment: which IDE are you using. eclipse? idea? something else?

Answer (score 3):

the most probable cause is that you have different java version installed next to 1.6 and you messed up your compiler settings. Make really sure that you're compiling against java 1.6 by running following in your java program:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

open Window > Show View > Console to see what the program prints.
Also, both Console View and Debug View show the jre used to execute the program.
If this shows that eclipse didn't use java 1.6, then go to project properties > java build path > Libraries > JRE System Library ... or have a look at Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

Comment: well, this command return '0'. Not really sure what that means

Comment: I didn't mean the exit value of the program. please open Window > Show View > Console and see what the program prints.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem in IntelliJ. We found out that the project-sdk we were using was Android 4.0.3 Platform. We just changed it to 1.6.0_25 java. Then we could import java.awt.Desktop . Kinda makes sense given that awt classes aren't available on Android. Its funny that the code ran fine even though the IDE showed us compile errors.